# AppCode unable to build/run my application on iOS device

Tags: xcode, appcode

After upgrading to XCode 8 I am no longer able to run or debug my application using AppCode.  I am running version of 2.16.2.3 of AppCode.   After attempting Run|Run from AppCode's menu I get the following error in the messages tool window.

```
Error:Build failed in 2s 432ms
Note:Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'
```

XCode is able to build, run and debug the application with no problem.  I have code signing identity set to Automatic/IOS Developer for all configurations of my target.  I've tried Invalidate Caches/Restart from AppCode but no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please share the build log from Messages tool window -> Show build log (the button on the left of toolwindow) in a ticket in [our tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/OC)? We will try to help.

Comment: Created IDEA-164649.  Includes contents of build log and zip file with contents my xcode project directory.   Thanks

Comment: Thanks, the issue was transferred to our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14584, could you please try the solution in the first commment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains support figured it out.  Some kind of bogus data in project.xcworkspace directory.  Cleaned that out and everything  is fine now.  See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-14584

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to update your IDE? I had a similar problem few weeks ago, but than after some version it disappeared.

Now, my AppCode version: AppCode 2016.3 EAP
        Build #OC-163.7743.19, built on November 9, 2016

Comment: Thanks Vlad but I'm on the current EAP.   Frustrating.  I can run from command line exact xcodebuild command AppCode is running and I get the same result.  It's not picking up something from my project's signing configuration or something.  Just don't know...